# How to show progress bar on AmCharts gantt segment?

Tags: amcharts, gantt-chart

I want to show a progress of a task segment (like here: http://www.officetooltips.com/excel/tips/gantt_chart_with_progress.html) using green bar inside task segment on AmCharts Gantt. Now I am using bullets as shown here http://www.amcharts.com/tips/using-bullets-gantt-chart/, but it is a little bit tricky approach.

Also, I've tried to add custom class names for graph-column-element using addClassNames property of AmChart and classNameField of AmGraph, but it does not work. Gantt documentation says that there is no custom class prefix for Gantt task segment https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/css-class-names/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot quite determine what you are requesting. Maybe this example will help.

- http://jsfiddle.net/13jbrn2e/1/

First, amCharts does allow some css control for gantt charts. The example you point to in your question is an older post, and I believe the api has since been updated. You should be able to use **addClassNames**.

- https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGanttChart#addClassNames

In your chart config...

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
    "type": "gantt",
    "theme": "light",
    "marginRight": 70,
    "addClassNames": true,
```

Use the DOM inspector of your browser to catch the css class names added.

This means you can do this in your css:

```
.amcharts-graph-column-element {
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: green;
}
```

Then if you set up your segments similar to this (sorry, this is dummy data forked from an amCharts gantt example that is not an exact fit I am sure for your data)...

```
}, {
    "category": "Smith",
    "segments": [ {
        "start": 10,
        "duration": 8,
        "color": "#29a329",
        "task": "Task #2"
    }, {
        "duration": 1,
        "color": "#ebfaeb",
        "task": "Task #2"
    } ]
}, {
```

...you could end up having a chart looking like this, which seems to match somewhat with the link you shared.

[image]

Comment: It seems I cannot add custom css class for concrete task segment. And using two or more segments is the only way to show progress of task.